# scale background image according to width and height of div CSS

Tags: css

Is there any way to get background image scaled according to div width and height ? Using only CSS.

Comment: Have you thought about the resolution problems you're gonna face with such an approach?

Comment: @mavili can you explain what problems i am gonna face ?

Comment: Like if your div is larger than the image size, then you're scaling the image to be larger than its actual size. Which will end up "pixelated" (whatever the word for that is). Unless you're sure your divs are never larger than the background image.

Comment: @mavili proper word for that is **aliasing**.

Comment: No aliasing is when the pixels are no longer obviously sharp because of a positioning adjustment or inefficient calculation in the renderer. For example, if you put a 10x10 red box on 0,0 it will be fine. If you put it on 0.5, 0.5, the edges will be aliased (1px light red line) to help tease your brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `background-size: cover` for my full-size bg images. If you don't like that result, you can set an image inside the div and give either of the following:

Full width of container, maintain aspect ratio:

```
width    : 100%;
height   : auto;
position : absolute;
z-index  : 0; /* something lower than content */
```

Full height of container, maintain aspect ratio:

```
width    : auto;
height   : 100%;
position : absolute;
z-index  : 0; /* something lower than content */
```

Full width and height of container, will warp & stretch:

```
width    : 100%;
height   : 100%;
position : absolute;
z-index  : 0; /* something lower than content */
```

Comment: But well, is there aliasing issue ?

Comment: Aliasing isn't the problem. The problem would be distortion from upscaling the pixels in a raster graphic. You just need to make sure the image is a high enough resolution to accommodate the largest possible container, or of course, use SVG.

Comment: Well, man just relying on `background-size:cover`. I can't start to learn SVG.